# What is the point of specifying Integer Choices in django models?

Tags: python, django

The official django docs give the following example for specifying integer choices for a column:

```
class Card(models.Model):

class Suit(models.IntegerChoices):
    DIAMOND = 1
    SPADE = 2
    HEART = 3
    CLUB = 4

suit = models.IntegerField(choices=Suit.choices)
```

However, I find that if I open 'python manage.py shell' and simply do something like:

```
c = Card()
c.suit = 5
c.save()
```

it saves the card with no problems, even though 5 isn't included in my choices. so what is the point of specifying my integer choices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of providing choices is for user provided data validation. Your forms won't accept any other input that the choices you defined.

As a developper, you are free to put any data you want, as long at it complies with the database constraints you defined.

You need to note that in the provided example, you did not validate your model before saving it. If you did so, it would have triggered an exception.

```
c = Card()
c.suit = 5
# Validation !
c.full_clean()
c.save()
```